# Invite facebook friends on wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, facebook-invite-friends

I want to have invite facebook friends functionality. I have made app on facebook and have app id.Now when I use any plugin or custom code for opening invite friends dialog box, it gives error of

> "Game Requests are only available to games."

I am not getting why this error coming? Can any one please help me? Do I need to change some settings in facebook app which I have created?

Comment: Check `category` you choose in your app setting. it seems you have chosen `Game` category.

Answer (score 0):

may be the below guide line will assist you.

You must set your Facebook app as a game [category](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/appcenter/categories), in the [App settings](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/). Otherwise, you can't use `GameRequestDialog`, because your app is not a game. In this case, Facebook gives you [AppInviteDialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android)